# Windows 10 - installed on external SSD , gets stuck on Windows logo after installing bootcamp drivers

Tags: bootcamp, windows, ssd

I installed windows 10 on an external SSD, on my Macbook pro. I saw this method from a 9to5 mac video. I followed each step, and it all worked flawlessly, i was even able to use windows 10, but then i installed the bootcamp drivers (The WindowsSupport folder installed from the bootcamp) After installing the drivers, i restarted, and well, the screen was stuck on the windows logo and the spinning dots were frozen.

Any help?

Comment: Which year Mac? Can you post a link to the video?

Comment: Windows 10 client doesn't support booting from an external device.  You need the enterprise version.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Windows 10 on an external SSD as well. I have experienced the same thing while I have my USB-C to HDMI adapter plugged in. Maybe you could disconnect all your USB-C connected devices but your SSD and try again?